# How to hide the activity in background without killing it?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a MainActivity and an Activity2. When I press a button on MainActivity, it starts the activity2 and on activity2 I have a button which when pressed i want to return to MainActivity without killing Activity2/releasing its resources(or hide the activity in background if possible). The button to launch activity2 is already achieved, but I don't know how can I hide the Activity2 on button press.

Answer (score 2):

Make your `MainActivity` launchmode to `singleInstance` in manifest

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

when clicking on button on Activity2 launch the `MainActivity` again

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably launch an intent that shows the home screen but not finish the Activity2

[Check More Details here](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basi...7-progmatically-go-home-screen.html#post59079)